# Value error while comparing a two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I am trying to compare the values of a particular column with one of columns, and store the result to a new column based upon their comparison index, say: Low if value differ by more than 10%, and OK if otherwise.

```
df["Index"] = ""
def function(df):
    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)-2):
        if((df.columns.values[1]) == (df.columns.values[i+1])):
            if((df.iloc[:,1]) < (0.9 * df.iloc[:,i+1])):
                df["Index"] = "Low"
            else:
                df["Index"] = "OK"
function(df)
```

What is the relation of

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

to this? Would be great if someone can as well suggest ways to reduce the time complexity using same code structure.

Comment: See `Series.shift` and `np.where`

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: `df['Index'] = np.where ( (df.iloc[:,1]) < (0.9 * df.iloc[:,i+1]),'Low','Ok')`.... you could show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: can u show an example expected input and output.?

Comment: The data is in following structure: `df = {'char':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],'Age1':[29, 27, 25, 26],'Age2':[60, 48, 55, 62],
      'Age3':[60, 48, 55, 62],'Age4':[60, 48, 55, 62],'Age5':[18, 19, 17, 12]}` Here, Age gets compared with one of the Age group, and if the values in Age is, say 90% less than that of Age1, df[Index] is assigned as Low, and if Age is 110% higher than Age1, Index is assigned as High, else Average. Age is the fixed column `df.iloc[:,1]`.

Comment: @ansev it returned the values of `df.iloc[:,i+1]` to index.

Comment: @PukarAcharya do you want to check `Age` against any of the columns after it? And if one of them is 90% less then result in 'Ok'?

Comment: @davidbilla Yes. If it is more by 1.1 times, then index is high. If it's less by 0.9 times, then the index is low, and OK if otherwise.

Comment: @PukarAcharya check my answer.. this is close to ansev's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to check Age against any of the columns after it? And if one of them is 90% less then result in 'Ok'? I am not sure if the logic you need is this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'char':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],'Age1':[29, 27, 25, 26],'Age2':[60, 48, 55, 62], 'Age3':[60, 48, 55, 62],'Age4':[60, 48, 55, 62],'Age5':[18, 19, 17, 12]})

df["Index"] = ""

def function(df):
    for i in range(1, len(df.columns)-2):
        df['Index'] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1] < 0.9 * df.iloc[:, i + 1], 'Low', 'Ok')


function(df)
```

Output:

```
  char  Age  Age1  Age2  Age3  Age4  Age5 Index
0    A   20    29    60    60    60    18    Ok
1    B   21    27    48    48    48    19    Ok
2    C   19    25    55    55    55    17    Ok
3    D   18    26    62    62    62    12    Ok
```

If I change one of the `Age` values to 1 so that the `Age[i+1]` columns are more than 90% then result is

```
  char  Age  Age1  Age2  Age3  Age4  Age5 Index
0    A    1    29    60    60    60    18   Low
1    B   21    27    48    48    48    19    Ok
2    C   19    25    55    55    55    17    Ok
3    D   18    26    62    62    62    12    Ok
```

Comment: `df['Index']=  [np.where(df.iloc[:, 1] < 0.9 * df.iloc[:, i + 1], 'Low', 'Ok') for i in range(1, len(df.columns)-2)]`.

Comment: `df['Index'] = ''` ...not neccesary

Comment: isn't this the same as `df['Age'] < (df[column-1] * 0.9) ?` feels like a strange way to loop when the last value will be the absoloute..?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure on the logic in the question, so I just did a edit to the code snippet in the question to ask if what I was thinking was right? We can remove the loop and be more pythonic, absolutely. I still don't understand the logic behind this, as it is always going to use the last column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the logic behind your question but if there are many columns you could consider to use something like

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'char':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],
                   'Age1':[29, 27, 25, 26],
                   'Age2':[60, 48, 55, 62], 
                   'Age3':[60, 48, 55, 62],
                   'Age4':[60, 48, 55, 62],
                   'Age5':[18, 19, 17, 12]})

cols2compare = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("Age")]

diz = {True:"Ok", False:"Low"}

df["Index"] = df[cols2compare].apply(lambda x: x["Age"] < x.max()*.9, 
                                     axis=1).map(diz)
```